# ExecutorService & Lambdas - difference between .execute(() -> ...) and .execute()

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice, java.util.concurrent

I have a class, which implements the `Runnable` interface, and is a task that once started will run indefinitely (a long-running thread).

```java
public class LongRunningTask implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //stuff happening here
    }

}
```

A simple `ExecutorService/ThreadPoolExecutor` creation:

```java
final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);
```

If the `LongRunningTask` is actually started/executed, I am able to observe the actual result of it, and so, I noticed this:

- if I pass it to be executed with `executorService.execute(() -> new LongRunningTask());`, it will not be executed at all, and there won't be a result.
- if I pass it to be executed with `executorService.execute(new LongRunningTask());` it will be executed just as it should be and there will be a result.

What's the difference when using the lambda syntax of `() ->`?

Comment: What do you think `() -> new LongRunningTask()` does? Try to rewrite it using non-lambda syntax (as anonymous class).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`execute` accepts a `Runnable` and then calls its `run` method at some point.

In your question, you demonstrated two ways of passing `execute` a `Runnable`:

- passing an object that implements `Runnable`:

  ```
  executorService.execute(new LongRunningTask());
  ```
- passing a lambda expression that accepts no arguments:

  ```
  executorService.execute(() -> new LongRunningTask());
  ```

In the first case, `new LongRunningTask().run()` would be called. Presumably, this is a method you implemented in `//stuff happening here`. That's the code you want to run, right?

In the second case, the lambda expression *is* the `run` method of the `Runnable`, so `new LongRunningTask()` will be run. Note that this does not call the `run` method of `LongRunningMethod` (the code that you want executed). This just calls the constructor.

If you really want to use a lambda expression (though I don't see the point), you can do:

```
executorService.execute(() -> new LongRunningTask().run());
```

Comment: That answer actually clarified everything, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This `executorService.execute(() -> new LongRunningTask());` will create a new Runnable object with body of `run` method as `new LongRunningTask()` so it will just create the object.

so `executorService.execute(() -> new LongRunningTask());` is equal to this

```
executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() { // this run method's body will be executed by the service
        new LongRunningTask(); // just create the object
    }
});
```

On the other side `new LongRunningTask()` is the runnable itself and its `run` method will be called which contains the actual executable code.

It can be further optimized with method reference as

```
executorService.execute(LongRunningTask::new);
```